# In C++ program how can I get the output in bold letters?

Tags: c++

In C++ program how can I get output in BOLD letters and in capital letters?
Suppose I want to print "Hello World" in BOLD and in Capital letters, then what should I add to my program?

Comment: It depends. What are you outputting *to*? The terminal? A GUI?

Comment: Bold output is going to depend on the system and destination (as in the previous comment). For pure text output, something like ncurses might be handy. Uppercasing can be harder than it looks if you want to support more than ASCII.

Comment: Your question is essentially not a question about C++.  Output formatting is very dependent on factors such as your operating system, and method of display.

Answer (score 4):

If your terminal supports [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), you can set the font to bold.  How to print uppercase letters should be obvious.

```
printf("\033[1m%s\033[m\n", "HELLO WORLD");
```

A more portable solution would be to use a library like [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Comment: "How to print uppercase letters should be obvious." - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_%E1%BA%9E: *it has no traditional upper case form*

Comment: @chris Fair enough, but I don't see how that's a problem here.  The OP can just type the literal uppercase text into the source code.  If you want to implement a `to_upper_case` function, you'll need to be careful.  But then again, there is already [`toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) in the standard library.

Comment: As far as I know, to use `toupper`, you would need to use a proper locale, but implementations are not required to support it. To be confident in the code being portable, you would need something like Boost.Locale, or plain ICU. Of course this worry goes away until you actually need to support internationalization, which you forever hope isn't in the near future.